# Chance of finding a job as a programmer in Istanbul, Turkey, without knowing the Turkish language?

Tags: job-hunting, language, turkey

Is it possible to get a programming job in Istanbul without knowing the Turkish language? Or knowing the basics of communication, say 400 words and maybe 20 sentences.

I intend to travel to Istanbul and seek a job (I am a software programmer) there. I do not master the Turkish language though, it's important that I know how likely I am to find a job. I am good at what I do - my job - and I am good at English.

If anyone has any experience, suggestion, offer, caution, recommendation, etc. they are appreciated.

Comment: Could you also describe why Turkish? Why not US or Canada for example?

Comment: @azerafati I don't know about US but for Australia and Canada my points are not enough. And I don't think US is easier. I am 29 with 7 years of work experience, and graduated with associate's degree. I may have a chance for some states of Canada. Considering the economical, social, international, and political situation of Iran, my current goal is to move out. I can improve my points in another country and relocate to a worthy final destination later.

Comment: @MahdiTahsildari if you can find an employer willing to sponsor you for a work visa in the US, I don't think there is any particular minimum language requirement.  That is, if the employer is satisfied with your language skills, that is enough.  I believe the same is true in Canada for a temporary work permit, but I don't know whether Canadian temporary permits can lead to immigration as can an H-1B visa.  If you are Iranian, however, you have bigger problems getting to the US in the form of the "travel ban."